# PyCharm: How to close "find usages" and return to console

Tags: pycharm

When I open the find usages window in pycharm (alt-f7), it takes the place of the console and I can't figure out how to return to the console without having to re-run the program. I've tried going through the little icons on the top and left but none of them seem to help. Sorry if this seems like a silly question; please let me know if there's a more appropriate place to ask.

I'm using PyCharm community edition 2016.3.2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the bottom left rectangular icon of the window. And now you may be in "3: Find", click "4: Run" and go back to the console.